# Existe alguma maneira de deixar o fechamento de tags do vscode como é o do sublime?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, html-tags

Quando se abre uma tag no sublime como `<div>` escreve o conteúdo e depois digita "`</`" ele fecha automaticamente a tag que foi aberta, sem precisar escrever `div`.

Tem como fazer isso no VsCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara é só setar essa opção nos Setting do VS Code.

No canto inferior esquerdo, clica no ícone de Engrenage, abre os Setting e procura por "close tag" ai é só marca e pronto.

Vc vai digitar `div+`<kbd>tab</kbd> e vai aparecer automaticamente `<div></div>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em último caso vc tb  pode  instalar alguma extensão exclusiva para isso, ela vai fechar automaticamente todas as suas tag

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Isac vdd  valeu o toque já editei []'s

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Existem algumas extensões que você pode baixar para executar essa tarefa. A extensão que eu uso é a **HTML Snippets**.

Para baixá-la, basta clicar no ícone que parece um *bloco de tetris* no seu VS Code, e na barra de pesquisa digite o nome da extensão e selecione a correta, que vai aparecer na lista logo abaixo da caixa de pesquisa. Após isso, clique em *install*. Pronto!

Espero que tenha ajudado, se tiver alguma dúvida, pode me perguntar. :D

Answer (score 0):

Fala ae, João!

Como eu faço bastante coisa em ReactJS, uso bastante tags no VSCODE, eu tenho essa config dentro do arquivo "settings.json"

```js
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
```

pra abir ele você faz assim: "Ctrl + P", digita ">settings" e clica em "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)".

Espero ter ajudado!